# How to Break From While Loop With Nested Each Block

Tags: ruby

I'd like to be able to escape from a `while` loop that has a nested `each` block.

In the example method below:

`@client` represents an API client.

`#recommended_photos` is an API call that returns an array of 20 recommended (unliked) photos. On subsequent API calls, this array can populate with new recommended photos until all have been liked.

```
def like_recommended_photos(limit = nil)
  liked_photos_count = 0
  recommended_photos = @client.recommended_photos
  while recommended_photos
    recommended_photos.each do |photo|
      @client.like photo
      liked_photos_count += 1
      break if limit == liked_photos_count
    end
    recommended_photos = @client.recommended_photos
  end
end
```

What I would like to do is optionally set a limit on the number of photos to be liked.

So if I called `liked_recommended_photos(5)`, I would only want 5 photos to be liked. However, this would end up liking all possible photos and I can't figure out how to properly stop the while loop.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet would be to eliminate the nested loop altogether.  I assume you've done this due to a possibility that `recommended_photos` can be nil?

If so, you could try something like this:

```
def like_recommended_photos(limit = nil)
  liked_photos_count = 0
  recommended_photos = @client.recommended_photos || []
  recommended_photos.each do |photo|
    @client.like photo
    liked_photos_count += 1
    break if limit == liked_photos_count
  end
  recommended_photos = @client.recommended_photos
end
```

That way `recommended_photos` is never nil and the loop will run on an empty array (and do nothing as a result), that way you can avoid messy `catch`/`throw` logic.